# can firefox extension modify DOM of HTML document then save as HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I am creating a firefox extension that lets the operator perform various actions that modify the content of the HTML document.  The operator does not edit HTML, they take other actions and my extension modifies the document by inserting elements, adding attributes, and so forth.

When the operator is finished, they need to be able to save the HTML document as a file (or have my extension send it to an internet destination, but this is not required since they can email the saved file).

I thought maybe the changes made by the javascript code in my extension would be reflected in the HTML document, but when I ask the firefox browser to "view source" after making modifications, it displays the original HTML text.

My questions are:

#1: What is the easiest way for the operator to save the HTML document with all the changes my extension has made?

#2: What is the easiest way for the javascript code in my extension to process the HTML document contents and write to an HTML file on the local disk?

#3: Is any valid HTML content incapable of accurate representation in the saved file?

#4: Is the TreeWalker part of the solution (see below)?

---

A couple observations from my research so far:

I've read about the TreeWalker object, which seems to provide a fairly painless way for an extension to walk through everything (?or almost everything?) in the HTML document.  But does it expose everything so everything in the original (and my modifications) can be saved without losing anything of importance?

Does the TreeWalker walk through the HTML document in the "correct order" --- the order necessary for my extension to generate the original and/or modified HTML document?

Anything obscure or tricky about these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I get to answer my own question, thanks to someone in mozilla #extdev IRC.

I got totally faked out by "view source".  When I didn't see my modifications in the window displayed by "view source", I assumed the browser would not provide the information.

However, guess what?  When I "file" ===>> "save page as...", then examine the page contents with a plain text editor... sure enough, that contained the modifications made by my firefox extension!  Surprise!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I am assuming here you have access to page DOM. What you need to do it basically make changes to the dom and then get all the dom code and save it as a file. Here is how you can download the page's html code. This will create an `a` tag which the user needs to click for the file to download.

```
var a = document.createElement('a'), code = document.querySelectorAll('html')[0].innerHTML;
a.setAttribute('download', 'filename.html');
a.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html,' + code);
```

Now you can insert this a tag anywhere in the DOM and the file will download when the user clicks it.

Note: This is sort of a hack, this injects entire html of the file in the a tag, it should in theory work in any [up to date browser](http://caniuse.com/download) (except, surprise, IE). There are more stable and less hacky ways of doing it like storing it in a file system API file and then downloading that file instead.

**Edit:** The `document.querySelectorAll` line accesses the page DOM. For it to work the `document` must be accessible. You say you are modifying DOM so that should already be there. Make sure you are adding the code on the page and not your extension code. This code will be at the same place as your DOM modification code, not your extension pages that can't access the DOM.

And as for the `a` tag,  it will be inserted in the page. I skipped the steps since I assumed you already know how to manipulate DOM and also because I don't know where you would like to add the link. And you can skip the user action of clicking the link too, but it's a hack and only works in modern browsers. You can insert the `a` tag somewhere in the original page where user won't see it and then call the `a.click()` function to simulate a click event on the link. But this is not a legit way and I personally only use it on my practice projects to call click event listeners.

I can only test this on chrome not on FF but try this code, this will not require you to even add the a link to DOM. You need to add this next to the DOM manipulation code. This will work if luck is on your side :)

```
var a = document.createElement('a'), code = document.querySelectorAll('html')[0].innerHTML;
a.setAttribute('download', 'filename.html');
a.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html,' + code);
a.click();
```

Comment: Your code seems to save a single element in the DOM document to a disk file.  What I need to do is save the entire HTML document to a disk file.  Do you know what you see when you select "view page source" from the browser menus?  Well, that's what I need to save - the entire HTML document, in HTML text format.  HOWEVER, after my extension makes lots of changes to the DOM (for example, inserts dozens of new elements with new attributes), what you see when you perform "view page source" is the original HTML loaded into the browser.  I need to save the HTML text that INCLUDES all the changes.

Comment: Yea this is the html tag which will be the entire page excluding the doctype and any attributes on the tag itself because the html tag always has all the code of the page. So it will be everything in the  `view source` page and I checked, the innerHTML does reflect any changes made to DOM via js, so you should be golden.

Comment: That is very cool, thanks!  Can you explain what each step does?  Also, is there any way I can do the same thing entirely with my extension code, so the operator doesn't have to do anything in the browser (like find and click a button)?  I assume what you show above is something I insert with the javascript in my extension, correct?  When you say "the file will download", I assume you mean the HTML document will be written into "filename.html" in the local filesystem of the operator (probably in some obscure path).  Can I specify a path, especially like "chrome://..." where my extension lives?

Comment: BTW, I had my extension javascript execute those lines after it had made 10 changes to the DOM, but the error console output the following error message: TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...)[0] is undefined.  Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: I can't figure out how to modify that document.querySlectorAll() line to make it work (not generate any error).  I tried reading documentation on the function, but it is way over my head!  Another question on your code.  You create the "a" element and then set two attributes on it, but you don't insert it anywhere in the DOM document.  Is that okay?

Comment: When the user will click the button, it will open a download prompt. Like any file you download from the internet. I made some assumptions when I wrote the answer, I will update it again to answer some of your other questions.

Comment: Woops!  Major, major woops!  My extension must work on any and all random web-pages (or HTML files) that anyone loads.  Therefore, my extension CANNOT control what is in the original HTML document... it can only add content via javascript in the extension, by calling functions like document.createElement() and element.setAttribute() and so forth.  So... do we need to start over and look for another way?

Comment: When you say you manipulate DOM does the webpage get changed or the extension page? If it's the extension page then I am afraid you will have to start over and rethink the app flow.

Comment: This is my first firefox extension.  I don't understand all the terminology, partly because my extension does less than most extensions.  My extension doesn't add/change firefox menu items or GUI elements.  My extension lets the operator of firefox pause his mouse cursor over any "term" (word, phrase or acronym) and add 1+ elements around them.  For example, he could set a new foreground (text) color, make the term boldface or italic, or add/set attributes proprietary to my application).  When done, he wants to save the HTML page!  That's ALL.  I don't even know what an "extension page" is!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this with the web API only, at least when you want a result that does not omit stuff like the doctype or comments. You could still write a serializer yourself that goes through `document.childNodes` and serialized according to the node type (`Element.outerHTML`, `Comment.data` and so on).

Luckily, you're writing a Firefox add-on, so you have access to a lot more (powerful) stuff.

While still not 100% perfect, the [`nsIDocumentEncoder`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/base/public/nsIDocumentEncoder.idl) implementations will produce pretty decent results, that should only differ in some whitespace and explicit charset declaration at most (everything else is a bug).
Here is an example on how one might use this component:

```
function serializeDocument(document) {
    const {
        classes: Cc,
        interfaces: Ci,
        utils: Cu
    } = Components;
    let encoder = Cc['@mozilla.org/layout/documentEncoder;1?type=text/html'].createInstance(Ci.nsIDocumentEncoder);
    encoder.init(document, 'text/html', Ci.nsIDocumentEncoder.OutputLFLineBreak | Ci.nsIDocumentEncoder.OutputRaw);
    encoder.setCharset("utf-8");
    return encoder.encodeToString();
}
```

If you're writing an SDK add-on, stuff gets more complicated as the SDK abstracts some important stuff away. You'll need to go through the [`chrome`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html) module, and also figure out the active window and tab yourself. Something like `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").content.document` ([Services.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm)) should do the trick.

In XUL overlay add-ons, `content.document` should suffice to get the document of the currently active tab, and you have `Components` access already.

Still, you need to let the user choose a file destination, usually through [`nsIFilePicker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFilePicker) and then actually write the file, by using something like a [file stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/File_I_O) or the fully async [`OS.File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread) API.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas and info.  I need to study the terms and functions in your message, because I'm not familiar with them.  What my extension will do is mind-boggling, but all the genius is in the C shared library and associated files, not in this simple extension.  As I said, my extension does no GUI or menus in the browser, but does display tiny borderless windows that let the user control the extension.  What I need is a mentor or contractor to help (once I explain what I'm doing, which I can't do in public).  If you'd consider this, email me at honestann -at- ymail -dot- com.  Thanks.

Comment: Some minor notes about slight differences in whitespace, obscure fields in the HTML document that might not serialize easily or naturally, and the character encoding of the document.  One way around some of that is to save and send the original document, plus the body of the modified document.  That way another application could insert the new body into the original document.  Also, due to the nature of my application, my extension really should save the document in UTF-8, even if the original was not in UTF-8.  If necessary, my application could ONLY function on UTF-8 documents.

Answer (score -2):

A browser has no direct write access to the local filesystem. The only read access it has is when explicitly provide a file:// URL (see note 1 below)

In your case, we are explicitly talking about javascript - which can read and write cookies and local storage. It can also send stuff back to the server and retrieve it, e.g. using AJAX.

Stuff you put in local storage/cookies is effectively not accessible to other programs (such as email clients).

It is possible to create very long mailto: URLs (see note 2) but only handles inline content in the email and you're going to run into all sorts of encoding issues that you're not ready to deal with.

Hence I'd recommend pursuing storage serverside via AJAX - and look at local storage once you've got this sorted/working.

Note 1: this is not strictly true. a trusted, signed javascript has access to additional functions which *may* include direct file access.

Note 2: (the limit depends on the browser *and* the email client - Lotus Notes truncaets the content rather a lot)

Comment: I suggest you re-read the question: The author explicitly asks about doing these things with a Firefox add-on, which has the same powers as the browser itself, incl. direct file read/write access. You're talking about access web content may or may not have, which is something entirely different.

Comment: Of course a browser has access to the file system. It's saving my downloads on the file system.